# Can't remove own question

Tags: support, self-delete, peer-pressure-badge

I got -4 and there's a badge for removing under peer pressure. I was thinking it's a good time to get it now (first time I get so downed, haha).

However, I can't do that. It says that I need to talk to a moderator.

How can I remove the question myself (and earn a badge in the process)?

Comment: I helped you upvote that because it's not a bad question honestly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Your question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17407534/should-we-always-specify-tostring-explicitly) has an upvoted answer, so it cannot be deleted; sorry to inform you!

Comment: Unacceptable! Now, the whole internet can see it. And me, being the center of everybody's daily attention, can't have it that way. :D (I wanted to get a new badge. It's been a while...)

Comment: @KonradViltersten Perhaps we could suggest a temporary suspension for such a terrible question. Comes with a nice shiny banner and everything! It's not perfect, but hey, we do what we can. ;)

Comment: @Bart Naaa, rather not. I've been suspended twice already. Both times with the best intentions trying to be helpful and clear on my standpoint. In fact, I ceased to contribute on CRM because apparently, people were **too** quick to grade me up. I've become much more "leechy" the last few months. I **really** dislike being suspended. I prefer badges to suspension, haha.